# NullPointerException while sending data from java server to c++ client

Tags: java, sockets

Sample.java

```
class Sample
{
    private BufferedOutputStream output;

    public handleRequest(Socket socket)
    {
        this.output = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), BUFFSIZE);
        sendString("sometext");//This is working fine
    }

    public void sendString(String str) throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream;
        bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(str.length());

        DataOutputStream out;
        out = new DataOutputStream(bytestream);

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            out.write((byte) str.charAt(i));

        output.write(bytestream.toByteArray(), 0, bytestream.size());
        output.flush();
    }
}
```

AnotherClass.java

```
class AnotherClass
{
    public send()
    {
        Sample smp = new Sample();
        smp.sendString("somestring");//This is not working
    }
}
```

whenever i'm calling sendstring method in AnotherClass.java it is give me an NullPointerExcetpiton.Iam unable to figure out .could any one please help me..Thanks in advace....

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't initialize

```
private BufferedOutputStream output;
```

So when you invoking

```
smp.sendString("somestring");//This is not working
```

`output` is null. You need to excecute method `public handleRequest(Socket socket){` to inilialize output strem first

**EDIT**

You could refactor your method and extract initialization to another method... But I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for..

```
public OutputStream initializeOutputStream(Socket socket, int size) {
     return new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), size)
}

public handleRequest(Socket socket)
{
    this.output = initializeOutputStream(socket, BUFFSIZE);
    sendString("sometext");//This is working fine
}
```

And then in `class AnotherClass` just use `public OutputStream initializeOutputStream(Socket socket, int size)` intead of `public handleRequest(Socket socket)`

Comment: i have a huge code in my handlerequest method..i cannot call that method..is there any other way around i can solve this issue...

Answer (score 1):

When you call `smp.sendString("something")` directly after the constructor of `Sample smp=new Sample();` you will have the NPE in following line

```
output.write(bytestream.toByteArray(), 0, bytestream.size());
```

because the `BufferedOutputStream`  `output` has never been initialized and therefore is `null`.